# laravel jquery dependent dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I have a simple drop down with a list of car manufacturers:

```
<label>Manufacturer
<select name="manufacturer" id="manufacturer" class="form-control input-sm" onchange="changeTwo(this.value)">
   </option>
   @foreach($manuf as $item)
  <option value="{{ $item->id}}">{{ $item->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
  </label>
```

That is fine and my idea was to have a second dependent dropdown populated by the choice so I have a javascript method:

```
function changeTwo(id)
    {
        var url = '{{ route("testDropdown",":id") }}';
        url = url.replace(':id', id);
        $.get(url, function (data){
            $('#model').empty();
            $.each(data, function(id,description){
                $('#model').append("<option value='"+ id +"'>" +description + "</option>");
            });
       });
    }
```

The route includes:

```
public function testDropdown($id)
        {
            $model = ModelRange::orderBy('description')->where('manufacturer_id',"=",$id)->get();
            return $model;
        }
```

my problem is that dropdown is populated by [object].

I have solved this using Laravel. I have a view called testtwo.blade.php

```
                    <label>Model
                        <select name="manufacturer" id="model" class="form-control input-sm" >
                            </option>
                            @foreach($model as $item)
                               <option value="{{ $item->id}}">{{ $item->description}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                           </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
```

and I amended the model to return the view:

```
 return view('test.testtwo',['model' => $model]);
```

and I simply replace the div with:

```
$('#modeldropdown').load(url);
```

Comment: change `$manuf` to `$model` in view

Comment: It is returning the correct items. Can;t quite understand your comment sorry.

Comment: sorry I should have made it plain there is a second dropdown in the view

Comment: So what are the issue  you are still facing?

Comment: I solved it Thanks!